# Maven local repository location for Linux and Windows

Tags: maven

I have a dual boot system with Windows and Linux. I have another partition which is visible to both Windows and Linux. I want to put my local repository there. How can I provide a path that both Linux and Windows will understand. Windows see it as `d:/repository` drive and Linux sees it as `/media/234242342/repository`. How should I configure this in `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Each OS needs an `M2_HOME` as per the Maven documentation. Inside `$M2_HOME/conf/` you can put a [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file and in that you can specify the location for the local repository using the `<localRepository/>` element.

So for your specific system, in Windows use

```
<localRepository>d:\repository</localRepository>
```

and in Linux

```
<localRepository>/media/234242342/repository</localRepository>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response

Answer (score 14):

You don't do that in the POM, but in your [`~/.m2/settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html), which would be different for both Linux and Windows, so no problem. See the [`localRepository`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Simple_Values) element:

```
<settings>
    <localRepository>d:\repository</localRepository>
    <!-- or -->
    <localRepository>/media/234242342/repository</localRepository>
    ...
 </settings>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can run  :

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository
```

[source](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/)

Answer (score 5):

It is located in the /home/.m2 directory, the folder is probably hidden. So, you'll need to press Ctrl+H to see hidden folders.

Comment: No, the URL of repository can be set to be anywhere, and can be set by many files. what you say is BY DEFAULT placement.

Comment: It's worked for me ,really it was hidden folder thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CentOS version 7 the Maven local repository will be:

```
/root/.m2/repository/
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just define both locations as separate repositories and let maven use the available one?

Or symlink `/media/234242342/repository` to `/repository` and use this path for both builds.

Also, have a look at [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), it might be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

> C:\Users<User_Name>.m2

Linux:

> /home/<User_Name>/.m2

Mac:

> /Users/<user_name>/.m2

And of course, for Linux and Mac, we can write in the short form:

> ~/.m2