# add a specific jar from maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

In `Eclipse` i forgot how to add a specific jar from `m2 repo` in the case that we have a maven project without the m2e Plugin in Eclipse

[image]

Comment: put it as a dependency in the pom.xml (can be found in the project root)

Comment: i already put it there but i must put it here to projrct can build because i dont use m2e so he dcant know where is it

Comment: ah yes... I would try "Add External jar" and then you have to search the lib in the local maven repo, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891984/maven-local-repository-location-for-linux-and-windows

Comment: Start using m2e makes life easier....

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate Eclipse metadata for your project, then restart Eclipse and, if needed, reimport your projects.

You'll need to repeat that for every dependency change. In the long run, you're probably better off using m2e.